# How can I remove the Time from a DateTime value?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

In my SQL database, I have a column formatted as `DateTime` and when I retrieve data from that column in ASP.NET, I catch it on the Date variable, than pass the value to textbox:

```
Dim Y As Date = dt.Rows(0)("SCH_DATE")
txtSchedDate.Text = Y.Date.ToString
```

but when I debug my website, the `txtSchedDate.Text` still gives me the full `DateTime` value:

```
7/17/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

is it possible to eliminate the time value here and just return the date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using something like

```
txtSchedDate.Text = Y.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

or which ever format you wish to display.

Have a look at

[DateTime.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent
>   string representation using the specified format.

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows(0)("SCH_DATE")).ToString("M/d/yyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get date by `txtSchedDate.Text = Y.Date.ToShortDateString()`

Answer (score 1):

Besides answers above, you can try converting it in SQL server

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15), GETDATE(), 11)
```

Keep in mind after converting it's `VARCHAR(15)` instead of `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `Date` object, you can get the constituent pieces if you wish as well, like this:

```
Dim Y As Date = dt.Rows(0)("SCH_DATE")
txtSchedDate.Text = Y.Date.Year & "-" & Y.Date.Month & "-" & Y.Date.Day
```

Or you can use the custom and standard date and time format strings mentioned by others.